# How avoid infinite loop during Json Serialization in Java

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, infinite-loop

I retrieve a list of Brothers using hibernate

```
public class Brother {
    public int brotherId;
    public string name;

    public List<Brother> brothers;

    public Brother()
    {
        brothers = new ArrayList<Brother>();
    }

    //Getter Setter
}
```

Hibernate is configured using lazy select in brothers list, this in Java side works,
But the problem is when I want to serialize a Brother object to JSON.

```
I've got org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

for Example Bryan can have Mark as brother an viceversa...

How I can solve it? is there any way to indicate max number of recursion to jackson libraries?

my code, it is really simple.

```
Brother brother = this.myservice.getBrother(4);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(brother));
```

Comment: could you add the code how you use Jackson?

Comment: You can use `@JsonIgnore` and for Jackson > 1.6 use : `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` on attributes to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: I will test. but if I use JsonIgnore the brother list will be ignored, I don't want that.

will @JsonBackReference generate something like this?

{
    "brotherId": 4,
    "name": "bryan",
    "brothers": [
        {
            "brotherId": 3,
            "name": "mark",
            "brothers": null
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can you post more code , and sample input / output . Also from future please use @sol4me that way I will be notified if you will write something to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is arising because of **Circular Reference**.

> Since `Jackson 1.6` you can use two annotations to solve the infinite
>   recursion problem without ignoring the getters/setters during
>   serialization: **@JsonManagedReference** and **@JsonBackReference**.

refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288939/286588) for more