# Recursive Objects Serialization issue with ORMLite 5 and Retrofit 2

Tags: android, serialization, gson, retrofit2, ormlite

I have 2 classes like the following code sample:

Class A

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "id")
private UUID id;
@ForeignCollectionField
private LazyForeignCollection<B, UUID> bList;
```

Class B

```
@DatabaseField(id = true)
private UUID id;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "idA", foreign = true)
private A objA;
@DatabaseField
private String foo;
```

I'm facing problems to send this data from android to an API using Retrofit2, because when I send A, the serializer call the bList and ORMLite automagically load it.

Each object of B in my bList have "objA" filled and every "objA" have a bList with data.
Its OK to the application because it's always the same object allocated, but the GSon serializer tries to serialize every level and throws this exception:

```
ERR: stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                            Caused by: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=760 (# cursors opened by this proc=760)
                                                               at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
                                                               at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
                                                               at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
                                                               at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.first(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:68)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.queryForOne(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:206)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedQueryForFieldEq.execute(MappedQueryForFieldEq.java:38)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.createForeignObject(FieldType.java:1047)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.assignField(FieldType.java:556)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:72)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:284)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:168)
                                                               at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.next(SelectIterator.java:181)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                               at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                               at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntime
```

and this:

```
09-11 09:59:16.618 28706-28747/br.com.igtech.nr18 D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 1636884
09-11 09:59:16.618 28706-28747/br.com.igtech.nr18 E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-11 09:59:16.628 28706-28747/br.com.igtech.nr18 E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                    android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4164)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
                                                                        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Mannualy setting the object to null can solve this issue, but I think it's not the best way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492342/how-avoid-infinite-loop-during-json-serialization-in-java/27498102#27498102) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue/18288939#18288939)

Solved changing the ConverterFactory from Gson to Jackson

```
retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

Jackson has the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations that solve the loop problem.